# How to identify which div element in in the viewport (or it is showing on screen) from multiple div element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an index on the left side of my page. I wanted to glow a particular index according to the div element, which is showing on the screen. And the index will change with scroll.
My code is working only for the element1, not working for other elements.
Can anyone help me to show the javascript code?

My Demo HTML Code:-

```
<div id="index1">
    <a>index1</a>
</div>

<div id="index2">
    <a>index2</a>
</div>

<div id="index3">
    <a>index3</a>
</div>



<div id="element1">
    <!-- code... -->
</div>

<div id="element2">
    <!-- code... -->
</div>

<div id="element3">
    <!-- code... -->
</div>
```

My Actual Js Code:-

```
function isInViewport(el) {
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)

    );
}

const e1=  document.querySelector('#element1');
const e2= document.querySelector('#element2');
const e3= document.querySelector('#element3');

document.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    if(isInViewport(e1)){
        document.querySelector('#index1').style.color = "white";
        document.querySelector('#index1').style.fontWeight = "bold";
    }else if(isInViewport(e2)){
        document.querySelector('#index2).style.color = "white";
        document.querySelector('#index2').style.fontWeight = "bold";
    }else if(isInViewport(e3)){
        document.querySelector('#index3').style.color = "white";
        document.querySelector('#index3').style.fontWeight = "bold";
    }
}, {
    passive: true
});
```

Comment: You have a typo, a missing single quote, in #index2 but I suspect that is not the only problem. What do you want to happen if there is more than one element in view at any one time? Should all the relevant indexes be highlighted or only the first one or...?

Comment: All relevant indexes should be highlighted.

Comment: You need to test each element each time, not stop after the first one that can be seen. You also need to unhighlight them if they are not in view. Also, what if part is in view. At the moment the whole element has to be in view so a long element will never be highlighted.

Comment: Thanks, man. That worked. All Credit goes to you.